# Проблема в коде мат. задания

Tags: f#

Вот задание:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
let rec fact n  = 
    if n<=1 then 1.0
    else float n*fact(n-1)


let rec step x n =
    if n=0 then 1.0
    else x*stepx(n-1)


let minus n =
    if n%2=0 then 1
    else -1

let otn x n = 
   minus n * stepx(2*n)/fact(2*n)
   minus n*(fun k -> step x k/fact k)(2*n)
   let mycos x = sum x 1.0E-6

let rec sum x n eps 
    let z = otn x n
    if abs z < eps then z
    else z + sum x(n+1) eps
```

Не могу понять почему не работает, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: Вот такие ошибки выдаёт, я не понимаю что не так, делал по примеру преподавателя

/home/jdoodle.fs(16,19): error FS0597: Successive arguments should be separated by spaces or tupled, and arguments involving function or method applications should be parenthesized

/home/jdoodle.fs(21,5): error FS0010: Unexpected keyword 'let' or 'use' in binding. Expected '=' or other token.

/home/jdoodle.fs(22,5): warning FS0058: Possible incorrect indentation: this token is offside of context started at position (21:5). Try indenting this token further or using standard formatting conventions.

Comment: Пожалуйста включите описание проблемы в текст вашего вопроса и отформатируйте, чтобы было возможно прочитать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первая проблема которая здесь есть - форматирование. В F# отступы имеют значения, обращайте внимание на сообщения IDE и компилятора.

Вторая проблема - последовательность объявлений. По умолчанию вы не можете вызывать функции до их определения. В вашем коде `mycos` содержит вызов функции `sum` которая находится ниже.

Опечатки - пропущенные символы `=`, пропущенные аргументы и так далее.

В остальном - все в полном порядке, разве что точность можно взять чуть побольше, привожу исправленный код и ссылку на песочницу для подтверждения:

```
let rec fact n  =
    if n <= 1 then 1.0
    else float n * fact (n - 1)

let rec step x n =
    if n = 0 then 1.0
    else x * step x (n - 1)

let minus n =
    if n % 2 = 0 then 1.0 
    else -1.0

let otn x n =
    let k = 2 * n
    minus n * step x k / fact k

let rec sum x n eps =
    let z = otn x n
    if abs z < eps then z
    else z + sum x (n + 1) eps

let mycos x = sum x 0 1.0E-8
```

https://repl.it/repls/OutlyingAttractiveCron